# PolymerJS: How to Update all Items in an Array with set() and a forEach loop properly

Tags: javascript, foreach, polymer

I have an array that looks like this:

```
items: [
    {title: 'First Title', completed: false}, 
    {title: 'Second Title', completed: false}, 
    {title: 'Third Title', completed: false}
];
```

I'd like to **set each** `item` to `true`. For this I have a button that fires an event on-tap that executes the following code snippets.

The Polymer team sets the Boolean value with a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; ++i) {
    this.set(['items', i, 'completed'], true);
}
```

I personally prefer to use a forEach loop, because I'd like to compare Polymer to different frameworks and it happens to happen that I am using `forEach` loops in similar cases.

**My working solution:**

```
var that = this;
this.items.forEach(function(item) {
    var i = that.items.indexOf(item);

    that.set('items.' + i + '.completed', true);
    // or
    // that.set(['items', i, 'completed'], true);
});
```

Specifically the part where I use `dots` to connect with `i` seems hacky to me.

---

**Same code with Vue**:

```
this.items.forEach(function(item) {
    return item.completed = true;                   
});
```

---

The Polymer API states:

> **set(path, value, root)** path (string|Array<(string|number)>)
>   Path to the value to read. The path may be specified as a string (e.g. foo.bar.baz) or an array of path parts (e.g. ['foo.bar', 'baz']). Note that bracketed expressions are not supported; string-based path parts must be separated by dots. Note that when dereferencing array indicies, the index may be used as a dotted part directly (e.g. users.12.name or ['users', 12, 'name']).
>   value * 
>   Value to set at the specified path.
>   root Object= 
>   Root object from which the path is evaluated.

---

**Question:**

Because the part where I use an index seems just a bit *hacky* for a lack of a better term, I wonder, **if there is a more convenient way to use a forEach loop in Polymer** to update all items in the Array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach`'s callback function can have a second parameter that refers to the current index. This also goes for Array's `map`, `every`, `some`, and `filter` methods.

## ES5 Version

```
this.items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  this.set('items.'+index+'.completed', true);
}.bind(this));
```

## ES6 Version

```
this.items.forEach((item, index) => this.set(`items.${index}.completed`, true));
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters

Comment: I think that's actually a slightly more confusing snippet. I guess your answer implies, that there isn't a more convenient way to `set` all items of an array in Polymer to `true`.